# A guess of linear map on infinite dimensional space.

Tags: linear-algebra, infinite-matrices

Let $V$ be a countable infinite dimensional linear space,
$$
e_1, e_2, e_3, \ldots
$$
are the basis of $V$.
$$
f: V \rightarrow V
$$
is a left invertible linear map. For any $e_i$, assume
$$
f(e_i)= f_{i1}e_1  +  f_{i2}e_2   + f_{i3}e_3   +\cdots.
$$
If there is a positive integer $R$ such that    for any $i\in \mathbb N$, the number of  nonzero elements of
$$
\{f_{ij}\}_{j=1}^\infty
$$
and the number of  nonzero elements of
$$
\{f_{ji}\}_{j=1}^\infty
$$
are  less than or equal to  $R$,  then how to show there is a left inverse  $f^{-L}$ of $f$ such that :

there is a positive integer $R'$ such that for any $i\in \mathbb N$, the number of nonzero elements of
$$
\{f_{ij}^{-L}\}_{j=1}^\infty
$$
and the number of  nonzero elements of
$$
\{f_{ji}^{-L}\}_{j=1}^\infty
$$
are less than or equal to $R'$ ?    Where $f_{ij}^{-L}$ is the coefficient of $f^{-L}$, namely,  for any $e_i$, we assume
$$
f^{-L}(e_i)= f_{i1}^{-L}e_1  +  f_{i2}^{-L}e_2   + f_{i3}^{-L}e_3   +\cdots.
$$

**PS:**  The left inverse of $f:V\rightarrow V$ is a map $f^{-L}:V\rightarrow V$ such that
$f^{-L}\circ f$ is identity mapping. Namely, for any $x\in V$, we have $f^{-L}\circ f(x)=x$. If such $f^{-L}$ exists, we say $f$ is left invertiable.  Notice that the left inverse maybe not unique in the infinite dimensional spaces.

**PS:**  This problem is  my guess. I think some examples, although there are some $f$ has left inverse which not satisfy the condition, but for there $f$, the left inverse is not uniquess, and I can find the one satisfy the condition. Thus I  sum up   guess, but after spending much time, I fail to prove it. I really want to whether it is right? If right, how to prove? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you provide a definition of a left inverse which you use?

Comment: @AlexRavsky  I have add it in question, thanks.

Comment: There are plenty of sparse matrices whose inverse is dense. I'm not sure that this conjecture is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further hypotheses the claim is false. Take a small perturbation of the identity like e.g.  $f(e_i)=e_i-  \epsilon e_{i+1}$, $i\geq 0$ and $\epsilon$ small but non-zero. This verifies the required conditions. Write $f={\bf 1} - A$ and develop $(1-A)^{-1}=1+A+A^2...$ Then $f^{-L}(e_i)=e_i+\epsilon e_{i+1} + \epsilon^2 e_{i+2} + ...$ converges (in any reasonable space) and does not have finite support in the indices.

Comment: Very thanks, this question perplex me some time, although it is false.